# Django Database is updating every on page load

Tags: django, post

```
def group_display(request, group_id):
    groups = Groups.objects.get(id=group_id)
    username = UserInfo.objects.get(owner = request.user)
    form = membership_form()
    template = 'groups.html'


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = membership_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.name = username
            post.group = groups
            post.save()

    context = {
               'form':form,
               }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The problem is that every time I reload page a new row is added to membership model. Seems like the page is loads as request.POST. is there any way i can insert the data only on button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1. Redirect after a successful POST.
2. Check to make sure there isn't a registration for that user.

Here is a view that takes care of both:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

def group_display(request, group_id):
    groups = get_object_or_404(Groups, id=group_id)
    username = get_object_or_404(UserInfo, owner=request.user)

    if username.membership_set.exists():
       # This user is already enrolled
       return redirect('/')

    form = membership_form(request.POST or {})
    template = 'groups.html'
    context = {'form': form}

    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.name = username
        post.group = groups
        post.save()

        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, template, context)
```

You'll have to adjust `username.membership_set.exists` based on your own models.

Answer (score 2):

After a successful POST request, it is best to return a redirect. This prevents the post request from being processed again if the page is refreshed. You can redirect to the current url if you want.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def group_display(request, group_id):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = membership_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.name = username
            post.group = groups
            post.save()
            return redirect('/success-url/')
    ...
```